# Are system() C functions ok?

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program that includes an ABOUT page. I was thinking that when user chooses to read that page, the console would clear (like if I execute clear command in linux bash) and show the about page content. 
After browsing a little I found this solution:

```
system("clear");
```

Is this ok? I mean, is this safe to use in a program? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: May I suggest a very cross-platform compatible alternative: Don't clear the screen :) Or alternatively you can write 100 empty lines to get an empty screen but your text would be at the bottom of the console instead.

Comment: @ssg: As I type this, I have a terminal window that's 105 rows tall. (It's running `tcvt` in a full-screen xterm window). If you want to clear the screen, just clear the screen -- though there's no *portable* way to do so. Or, as you suggest, consider not clearing the screen and possibly erasing the user's information.

Comment: @KeithThompson I assumed that the "about page" would be at least half a screen high, addressing most term configurations, but you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a sense that `system` is a part of the standard C library, the function itself is entirely safe. The problem is in the command portion of the call, i.e. `"clear"` in your example. This is heavily system-dependent, making your program non-portable.

A common solution to this problem is to supply the commands separately from your program (e.g. in a file) or to define them in a portion of your code that compiles conditionally. The first solution is slightly more flexible, but the second solution is easier to implement.

> How could I implement a solution that would execute `system("clear")` for Linux Terminal and `system("cls")` for Windows Terminal?

The approach with conditional compile would look as follows: first, put these definitions in your program

```
#ifdef WIN_TERMINAL
#define CLEAR_COMMAND "cls"
#endif
#ifdef UNIX_TERMINAL
#define CLEAR_COMMAND "clear"
#endif
```

Now use this command in your code:

```
system(CLEAR_COMMAND);
```

When you compile on UNIX, pass `-D UNIX_TERMINAL` when compiling your program. This usually goes into your `Makefile`. On Windows, pass `/D WIN_TERMINAL` to the compiler. This usually goes in the preprocessor flag list of your Visual Studio project.

Comment: @bauer A better way to put it is that getting good portability on code that uses `system` requires a somewhat significant effort.

Comment: It's not "entirely safe" if there happens to be a `clear` command in the user's `$PATH` that does something nasty. (I mean, even nastier than clearing the screen.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How could I implement a solution that would execute system("clear") for Linux Terminal and system("cls")  for Windows Terminal?

Comment: @KeithThompson , what would be the nastiest thing it could happen?

Comment: @bauer: That's equivalent to "What would be the nastiest thing a program or script can do". I can install a script that reformats the root hard drive, or sends an obscene e-mail to everyone in your address list, and name it `clear`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Therefore, I should let the screen as it is, correct?

Comment: @bauer: `system("/usr/bin/clear");` is likely to be safer -- and realistically there isn't all that much risk of a malicious `clear` command. In my opinion, clearing the screen just isn't a good idea in general. If your program uses curses and controls the entire screen, it's going to clear it anyway (and restore it when it exits, assuming the appropriate configuration). If it's just printing output to stdout, clearing the screen is IMHO rude. I have information on my screen; that's why I don't use a 1-line terminal. If I want my screen cleared, I can clear it myself thankyouverymuch.

Comment: @bauer Well, if you let someone copy a nasty program onto your system, you have a bigger security issue going on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , those definitions you insert in your comment are intended to write on *.c file(s) where system(CLEAR_COMMAND) is suppose to be executed, correct?

Comment: @bauer Correct, the definitions go near the top of that file, or if you plan on using `clear` from  multiple places, the definitions would go into a header file.

Comment: @KeithThompson `IFS=/ commandThatRunsSystem`  Now that `system("/usr/bin/clear")` call runs as `system("usr bin clr")`, using the `PATH` supplied by the user's environment.

Answer (score 2):

Advantage: It is a fast, well-defined method, because there is no other "*ready function*" to do this.

Disadvantage: It is OS dependant. On Windows, you will need to use `system("cls")`.

Comment: So, as far as I understood, system() function are safe but they have no good portability, correct?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that there is no standard function to do it, and there are libraries, for most operating systems that can send control characters to terminals in order to achive this kind of thing, not all terminal emulators will support them though.

Comment: @bauer, no, that has nothing to do with the `system()` function, it's the command.

Answer (score 0):

There are major disadvantages to running a the command via system.  Firstly there are security implications and differences of platforms.

Ideally you should print the platforms escape sequences to produce the desired result, or interface with the platforms API.  This will reduce dependencies that the cls / clear commands exist, as well as prevent undesired results if those commands are not standard.

Comment: There is no such security implication to using the `system()` C function and an OS-dependent terminal clear command. If the source code is kept on the system in question, not compiled, and someone that knows a thing or two about C code finds it and changes the code, then there is a much bigger security issue than a `cls` or `clear` command called in the C `system()` function...

Comment: There are inherent issues, such as if someone has access to the executable it is easy to find and insert a malicious command.  Secondly you are adding a dependency outside of the executable, which may or may not exist in the PATH or in a specified path, making the code less portable.  I would definitely not accept this in a code review.